# Filtering distinct items with identical M2M relations in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have created a few Django models to be used for registering games in a league. Somewhat simplified, this is what it looks like.

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(u"First name", max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(u"Last name", max_length=50)


class Match(models.Model):
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Participant)
```

I decided to relate the models via M2M as I wanted to easily query for games included a certain participant, which felt cumbersome if I had opted for using two fields with `"player_one"` and `"player_two"`. This also makes the system somewhat flexible in terms of adding games with more than two participants.

Anyway, some leagues will allow two players to face each other more than once, and it also allows for some free form scheduling meaning one player can play 20 games when another has only played 8.

Q: How would I craft a query that lets me filter all matches containing only unique matchups? I. e. Jen has played 12 games, but three of those were vs Paul, and I only want to count one of those to get a list of all the unique opponents she's faced.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: Probably, this solution is not efficient and i am sure there are better ones.**

If you are OK with changing model structure, you can add another field `unique_matches` to `Participant` model:

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(u"First name", max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(u"Last name", max_length=50)
    unique_matches = models.ManyToManyField(Match)
```

Then, when you need to create a new `Match` record, you can check `if did these players played against eachother before?`. And update `unique_matches` field according to that:

```
# assume request.user is jen right now
paul = Participant.objects.get(id=3)
if not paul in request.user.unique_matches.all():
    request.user.unique_matches.add(paul)
```

You can make this control after every `Match` record created.

Later, if you query like:

```
matches = request.user.unique_matches.all()
```

this will give you unique matchups.

#### Second Solution

If you want to keep existing model structure, you can try something like this (*Actually this may be a better approach*) :

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(u"First name", max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(u"Last name", max_length=50)


    def unique_matches(self):
        matches = self.match_set.all()
        uniques = []
        for match in matches:
            for player in match.players.all():
                if (player.pk != self.pk) and (not player in uniques):
                    uniques.append(player)

        return uniques
```

Then you can use this method anywhere like:

```
matches = request.user.unique_matches()
```

I did not test these solutions. If any error occurs please tell me and we can try to fix that.